# Paperclip stores photo file on different location on filesystem than photo.path or photo.url says

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, sti

I'm using Paperclip in my rails app to upload images to the filesystem. I furthermore use single table inheritance for an Incident model. Damage inherits from Incident. 
When I now create a new Incident object of :type => 'Damage' with a photo attached, something strange happens:

- object.class --> Damage
- object.url --> *"/system/**damages**/photo_images/000/000/265/original/my_image.png?1441880763"*
- object.path --> *"/Users/fuzz/keeja/backend/keeja_backend/public/system/**damages**/photo_images/000/000/265/original/fav_icon.png"*

  has_attached_file :photo_image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

And now comes the strange part. The actual path of the uploaded file is not one of the above, but: */Users/fuzz/keeja/backend/keeja_backend/public/system/**incidents**/photo_images/000/000/265/original/fav_icon.png"*

So Paperclip stores the file under a different path on the file system, than object.path says.

Can anyone please help me find out what's going wrong here?

Comment: Out of curiosity -- When you initialize your class, do you specify `Damages.new` / `Damages.create` / etc or `Incidents.new` / `Incidents.create` / etc? It sounds like you may be working with the abstract class, not a subclass. Try directly creating an instance of the subclass if not.

Comment: I do a Incident.new in the create method of the IncidentsController. When I use Damage.new, it works. Even though it doesn't create the :medium and :thumb version of the image (see the edit).

Comment: Ok, so that is a new question perhaps :) Not sure on that one.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Thanks for the hint. I don't know why Paperclip is behaving this way, but at least it's working now :-)

Comment: It's because in STI the base class can be instantiated so Paperclip thinks it's a different model. Check this out if you want to prevent such bugs, it may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850418/rails-sti-prevent-base-class-from-instantiation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Damage.new` / `Damage.create` / etc. instead of instantiating a new `Incident` to solve the path problem.